# Remove comma if field is a blank value in concatenation in SQL - Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I am trying to concatenate BLOCK_ID1, BLOCK_ID2 and BLOCK_ID3 into one string in BLOCK_ID. I want to remove the last comma in the string.

MyDE

| UNIQUE_ID | BLOCK_ID1 | BLOCK_ID2 | BLOCK_ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| B | 1 | 2 |  |
| C | 1 |  |  |

When i do:

```
SELECT UNIQUE_ID,
CONCAT(BLOCK_ID1,', ', BLOCK_ID2, ', ', BLOCK_ID3) as BLOCK_ID
From MyDE
```

OUTPUT DE:

| UNIQUE_ID | BLOCK_ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1, 2, 3 |
| B | 1, 2, |
| C | 1, |

I want to remove the last comma from B and C

Comment: hi, that's something you can just google, you just have to know the kind of SQL the marketing cloud uses - it's t-sql / Transact-sql. I did that just last week googling for `t-sql remove last character comma` and the solution here helped me: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6dc6daa4-7366-4f8d-8c61-0f3406b00b87/remove-last-comma-from-the-string?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the information that Marketing Cloud uses T-sql from Jonas Lamberty's answer, I figured a way to solve my problem.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
UNIQUE_ID,
CONCAT(BLOCK_ID1 + CASE WHEN BLOCK_ID2 = '' then '' else ', ' end,
BLOCK_ID2 + CASE WHEN BLOCK_ID3 = '' then '' else ', ' end,
BLOCK_ID3

) as BLOCK_ID

From myDE
```